# may be used uninitialized in this function -cpp

Tags: c++

We are getting this error:

```
switch(type)
            {

                case genericNode::GROUP_ID:
                    groupIdNode* temp;
                    *temp= groupIdNode(key);
                    return temp;
```

[The error that showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDNqc.png)

would love to get some help to try and solve it.
thank you :)

Comment: `temp` is a pointer that is never assigned, yet you dereference it on the lhs of the assignment. Using any member of an object via an uninitialized pointer is undefined behaviour. The assignment operator is a member...

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is a *pointer* to an object of type `groupIdNode`. It's value is not initialized. There is no statement `temp = something`.

`*temp=groupIdNode(key);` copies the return value of `groupIdNode` to the object *pointed to* by `temp`.   `*temp` takes the value of the pointer (not initialized), dereferences it and assigns it the return value.

... which will lead to an access violation and your program will crash.

`temp` is like a memory address where the actual object is stored. Since `temp` has not been initialized, it's contents are random (or 0).

`*temp` takes that memory address and assumes that there is an object of type `groupIdNode` at that address. Since the address has not been initialized, the program will crash.

Please: DO NOT USE POINTERS if you are starting to write C++ code. Pointers are hardly neccessary in modern C++. I view it as a big, huge problem that pointers are still allowed and even taught to C++ beginners. Pointers require a good understanding of basic programming principles and "indirections".

Comment: ok so what can we use instead of pointers?

Comment: Anything else. Why would you use pointers in the first place? There is a difference between an object (a variable) and a pointer to an object (the pointer itself is also a variable, but of a different type).   In most cases you will want to use objects themselves.  Like `float variable; variable=10.5f;`